# listings: Break long hexadecimal in multiple lines

Tags: listings, line-breaking

For our bachelor project, we are implementing an encryption algorithm. Our implementation is of course explained in a report written with LaTeX.

The encrypted cyphertext is a very long hexadecimal value. Just using `\lstinputlisting[title=ciphertext]{encrypted_cyphertext.txt}` will result in the text running off the right side of the page, as listings will only break on word separators; a hexadecimal value is treated as a single (very long) word.

Is there any way to break *inside* of words using the `listings` package?

Comment: Please add a small compilable LaTeX document that illustrates your problem and that allows us to propose solutions. Just use the `edit` button left below your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{encryption}
 {morekeywords=X, %one keyword is needed ...
  otherkeywords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,a,b,c,d,e,f},
  }
\textwidth=3cm

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines,breakindent=0pt,language=encryption]
546869732069732061206c6f6e67207465787420696e206865786164657a696d616c
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to break on all characters? Something similar to `minted`'s `breakanywhere` option.